# Accordion CSS Sizing Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sharepoint

I have made a dropdown menu with parent and child rows to display certain controls. I am unable to get the width of the Accordion (which is set to 100%) to actually stretch the entirety. I used the Chrome and Edge built in developer tools to inspect the HTML and find out what element has a width set which is preventing my rows from growing.

Here is what the dropdown currently looks like on my SharePoint page. I want it and its contents to stretch all the way across the page, but instead it is only stretching halfway?
[image]

Here is my JSFiddle test case: https://jsfiddle.net/tb36jsew/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.retro').accordion();
  
});
```

```css
.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title, .ui.styled.accordion .title {
  color: black;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 200%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.title{
  width: 200%;
  height: auto;
}
.title.drop{
  width: 100%;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.ui.styled.accordion {
  width: 200%;
  height: auto;
}
.ui.stackable.grid.container.retro{
  width: 200%;
  height: auto;
}
.one.column.row{
  width: 200%
  height: auto;
}
.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title, .ui.styled.accordion .title:hover {
    color: #f2711c;
}
a.previous {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #b3ab7d;
}
a.previous:hover {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: #b3ab7d;
}
.backbtn{
  padding-left: 0px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.previous {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: #b3ab7d;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.3.1/dist/semantic.min.css">


<div class="ui stackable grid container retro">
                    <div class="one column row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="ui styled accordion"> <!-- Accordion parent -->
                                <div class="title"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>Level 2</div>       
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                    <div class="ui stackable grid container">
                                        <div class="one column row">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.041 Ensure that the actions of individual system users can be uniquely traced to those users so they can be held accountable for their actions.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.042 Create and retain system audit logs and records to the extent needed to enable the monitoring, analysis, investigation, and reporting of unlawful or unauthorized system activity.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.043 Provide a system capability that compares and synchronizes internal system clocks with an authoritative source to generate time stamps for audit records.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                      <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.2.044 Review audit logs.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  <div class="one column row">
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="ui styled accordion"> <!-- Accordion parent -->
                                <div class="title"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>Level 3</div>       
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="ui divider"></div>
                                    <div class="ui stackable grid container">
                                        <div class="one column row">
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.045 Review and update logged events.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.046 Alert in the event of an audit logging process failure.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.048 Collect audit information (e.g., logs) into one or more central repositories.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                      <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.049 Protect audit information and audit logging tools from unauthorized access, modification, and deletion.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.050 Limit management of audit logging functionality to a subset of privileged users.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.051 Correlate audit record review, analysis, and reporting processes for investigation and response to indications of unlawful, unauthorized, suspicious, or unusual activity.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="column">
                                                <div class="ui styled accordion">
                                                    <div class="title drop"><i class="dropdown icon"></i>AU.3.052 Provide audit record reduction and report generation to support on-demand analysis and reporting.</div>
                                                    <div class="content">
      
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="backbtn">
<a href="/cyber/controls.aspx" class="previous">&laquo; Go Back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it what you trying to do?: https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/xed78qac/8/

Comment: If it's what you tried I will make an answer for it  - html wasn't good and there are some few things to fix in the css. If it is not wht you tried to do, please try to edit your question si it will be clearer

Comment: Very much so,  what was the issue?

Comment: @IsraGab Thank you. I figured out it was the `.ui.styled.accordion` element that had a width of 600px applied to it. Please create an answer so I can give you the credit you deserve for assisting me

Comment: cool! so please make a favor and accept the answer :)

Comment: @IsraGab just did, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add a closing `div` before `.backbtn` in the html

```html
      </div>
    <div class="backbtn">
```

then in css:

- add `width: auto;` in `.ui.styled.accordion .accordion .title, .ui.styled.accordion .title`
- remove all width: `200; height: auto`
- **most important** add following at the end of your css

```css
.ui.styled.accordion{
  width: auto !important;
}
```

You need it to override semantic-ui

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/sg06x4rc/4/